# Example based on maximum principle for heat equation

Tags: heat-equation, maximum-principle

Let $R =\{ (x,t)~|~ 0 < x < \pi,~0\le t \le T \} $  and $u$ solves the heat equation with $$u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0,~0 \le t \le T $$
$$ u(x,0) =\sin^{2}(x),~0\le x \le \pi. $$
Then how by using maximum principle we can show that $0 \le u(x,t) \le e^{-t} \sin{x}~$ in $R$.

Comment: For $0\leq a\leq 1$ we have $a^2\leq a$, so $0\leq\sin^{2}(x)\leq\sin(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$. And $e^{-t} \sin{x}$ is the solution for $u(x,0) =\sin(x)$, while $0$ is the solution for $u(x,0) =0$.

Comment: Ok, I understand this @Conifold but where we are using maximum principle?

Comment: The comparison principle used is a direct consequence of the maximum principle, see [Heat equation, p.76](http://www.mathmods.eu/resources/downloads/finish/13-ronghua-pan/52-apde-chapter04): if for two solutions $u-v\geq0$ initially the same inequality holds for all times.

Comment: got it, thanks.